# Web analytics in Sharepoint 2013 as 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, web-analytics

In Sharepoint 2010 i have good reports as shown on picture below:
[image]

What is the best way to get same result in SharePoint 2013?

I can not use ootb solutions.
Solution must consider users, who dont have internet access.
So, a want to have reports:

- Summary
- Traffic
- Top pages
- Top visitors
- Etc. such as in picture above
  (same reports)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Google Analytics tool . It can give you all the necessary results which you need .

http://davecoleman146.com/2011/01/31/adding-google-analytics-to-your-sharepoint-2010-site/

There is only a javascript which needs to be added in master page and all traffic is captured by Google .

OR

If you are ready to spend some money , use the WEB Trends tool . Its good and Microsoft itslef uses Web trends to track the users.

Comment: Check Hairpoint tool as well.

Answer (score 1):

As MSFT change the Web Analytics in 2013 and now we have only popularity trends or popularity reports ( event these reports are in excel). alot of 3rd parties in the market for this.

i love Google analytic but due to your internet access restriction. i would recomend to try [CardioLogic Analtics](http://www.intlock.com/intlocksite/productsandservices/cardiolog/cardiolog-analytics.asp).

"CARDIOLOG ANALYTICS
CardioLog Analytics is the only web analytics solution designed for SharePoint (versions 2013, 2010, 2007 and 2003) and SharePoint Online. It enables you to improve the usability of your intranet, drive portal collaboration, boost your ROI and enhance the overall productivity of your business."

Or Web trends are good too.
http://sharepoint.webtrends.com/reporting